# Cython: have sequence of Extension Types as attribute of another Extension Type with access to cdef methods

Tags: python, c++, cython

Suppose I defined the following Cython class

```
cdef class Kernel:
    cdef readonly double a

    def __init__(self, double a):
        self.a = a

    cdef public double GetValue(self, double t):
        return self.a*t
```

Now I'd like to define another Extension Type that has a sequence of Kernels as attribute. Something like:

```
cdef class Model:
    cdef readonly Kernel[:] kernels
    cdef unsigned int n_kernels

    def __init__(self, Kernel[:] ker):
        self.kernels = ker
        self.n_kernels = ker.shape[0]

    cdef double Run(self, double t):

        cdef int i
        cdef double out=0.0

        for i in range(self.n_kernels):
            out += self.kernels[i].GetValue(t)

        return out
```

However, this doesn't work. First I need to substitute `Kernel[:]`with `object[:]`, otherwise i get the following error from `gcc`

```
‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘__pyx_vtab’
```

If I use `object[:]` everything compiles fine but I get an error when attempting to access `GetValue`method:

```
AttributeError: "AttributeError: "'cytest.Kernel' object has no attribute 'GetValue'" in 'cytest.Model.Run'
```

#### What I would like

1. Access the `cdef` methods of `Kernel` from the `cdef` method `Run`, without Python overhead.
2. Type-check the elements of kernels.

#### My current workaround

At the moment I use the following solution which however doesn't satisfy the requirements above:

```
cdef class Kernel:
    cdef readonly double a

    def __init__(self, double a):
        self.a = a

    cpdef public double GetValue(self, double t):
        return self.a*t 

cdef class Model:
    cdef readonly object[:] kernels
    cdef unsigned int n_kernels

    def __init__(self, object[:] ker):
        self.kernels = ker
        self.n_kernels = ker.shape[0]

    def Run(self, double t):

        cdef int i
        cdef double out=0.0

        for i in range(self.n_kernels):
            out += self.kernels[i].GetValue(t)

        return out
```

i.e. I declare the methods of the Kernel class as `cpdef` so that they can be accessed to from Python and use `object[:]`.

#### Question

Is there a way to achieve points 1 and 2 above in Cython without Python overhead?

Thanks in advance for your time.

NB: I don't know the length of the sequence in advance.

#### Edit

Following @DavidW advice I modified the code as follows

```
# module cytest
import cython

cdef class Kernel:
    cdef readonly double a

    def __init__(self, double a ):
        self.a = a

    cdef public double GetValue(self, double t):
        return self.a*t


cdef class Model:
    cdef readonly Kernel[:] kernels
    ### added this attribute 
    cdef Kernel k 
    cdef unsigned int n_kernels

    def __cinit__(self, Kernel[:] ker):
        self.kernels = ker
        self.n_kernels = ker.shape[0]

    cpdef double Run(self, double t):

        cdef int i
        cdef double out=0.0

        for i in range(self.n_kernels):
            # now i assign to the new attribute each time 
            # and access the cdef method from it
            self.k = self.kernels[i]
            out += self.k.GetValue(t)

        return out
```

Now it compiles and runs fine (and faster than my previous workaround), even if I still have some python overhead when accessing the `Kernel[:]` attribute.

I put here an example of building and calling a `Model`

```
import cytest
import numpy as np

ker_list = [cytest.Kernel(i*1.0) for i in range(3)]

# transform it to a numpy array
# to be able to pass it to the 'Model' constructor
ker_arr = np.array(ker_list)

# create a model instance
model = cytest.Model(ker_arr)

# call the method Run
print model.Run(1.0)
```

Comment: I think it's just that you've missed the `[i]` index lookup - i.e. `out += self.kernels[i].GetValue(t)`

Comment: @DavidW Thanks. I fixed the mistake in the example I give, however that's not the cause of the probelm.

Comment: I failed to make a working test case for this (it seemed tricky to build the `Kernel[:]` memoryview to pass to the `Model` constructor). My suggestion would be to add `cdef Kernel k` earlier, and change the loop line to `k = self.kernels[i]; out += k.GetValue(t)`. This compiles, but I couldn't test if it worked. I also don't know how much type-conversion/checking overhead it would add, if it did work. If that doesn't work for you, can I suggest you edit to show how you actually build and call a `Model` instance.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you very much. Your suggestion works, in that the code with `Kernel[:]`compiles and `out += k.GetValue()`is able to access the `cdef`method correctly. 
It is true that there is still the python overhead when executing `k = self.kernels[i]`. However, I did a simple test with my actual problem and the version with `Kernel[:]`+`cdef' is faster by about a factor 2 compared with `object[:]`+`cpdef`.