# cython C code compilation fails with typed memoryviews

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cython

The following code compiles without issues in cython:

```
cdef class Double:
    cdef double v
    def __init__(self, double v):
        self.v = v
    cdef double incr(self) nogil:
        self.v += 1
        return self.v

cdef int f(Double[:] xs):
    cdef int i, N
    N = xs.shape[0]
    for i in range(N):
        xs[i].incr()
    return 0
```

However, when I try to compile the generated C code, the gcc compiler stops with an error:

```
test.c: In function '__pyx_f_4test_f':
test.c:1491:55: error: 'PyObject {aka struct _object}' has no member named '__pyx_vtab'
     ((struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4test_Double *)__pyx_t_3->__pyx_vtab)->incr(__pyx_t_3);
```

Where is the error I am making?  Note that the same code does not have any problem when I use standard memorytypes (for example, with a `double[:] xs` parameter in the `f` function).

Additionally, is there a way to release the gil inside the `f` function with `Double[:]`?  If I try that, I get an error message

```
test.pyx:13:10: Cannot access buffer with object dtype without gil
```

Looking at the generated code, I see a couple of calls to `__Pyx_INCREF` and `__Pyx_DECREF`, which however seems not needed to me.

**EDIT**

Following some discussion, I can now find workarounds and be able to compile the C code: for example use `object[:] xs` in the function definition, and then cast `(<Double>(xs[i])).incr()` in the for loop.  However, these workaround introduce even more python interaction, which is really what I would like to avoid.

In more general terms, the question is: *is there a way in cython to deal with a homogeneous list of `cdef class` (a typed buffer or similar) so that there is no python overhead and the GIL can be released?*

Comment: any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this topic, your case is probably similar to it:
[Cython: have sequence of Extension Types as attribute of another Extension Type with access to cdef methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119510/cython-have-sequence-of-extension-types-as-attribute-of-another-extension-type)

Please also try Googling for `__pyx_vtab` - search results shows questions from peoples who has similar problem, I checked first one briefly and looks that some solution is there too:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/3tUDIc11Xak

Comment: Thank you.  The question you linked is indeed very similar, I overlooked it: however, no answer has been provided, and there is only a workaround suggests.  The workaround, however, introduces python overheads.  Also, I still do not understand why cython is putting the __Pyx_INCREF in the code , and therefore cannot use these constructs in a fast, parallel way.  The question therefore is still unanswered.

Comment: Forgot to mention: the Google suggestion did not work, there are only a few pages discussing similar issues, but no solution that applies to my case: in particular, the page you mentioned discussed a problem quite different, arising from a list of parent-children classes defined in different files.